# How can I set the rootViewController from my UIViewController in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a UIViewController with a button.

This button has a method that should switch to another UIViewController. Previously I had it handled by:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("moveToMainWindow", sender: self)
```

but I would like to change it to something like:

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let tabBarVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainWindow") as? TabController {
    self.rootViewController = tabBarVC

 }
```

however this line `self.rootViewController = tabBarVC` brings error that value of type viewcontroller has no member rootViewController.

Is there anything I could fix here so that it could possibly work?

I want to avoid doing `performSegueWithIdentifier` because later on I'm doing couple times `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})` and in that case also my `MainWindow` panel gets dismissed. So I thought if I change the type of segue here this panel will never be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rootViewController` property is property on `UIWindow` that defines first or root view controller that is displayed when you application starts, and you can't set it as property on view controller.

What you can do instead of pushing view controllers with segues is to initiate view controller via storyboard and then push it using `showViewController:` or `presentViewController:` method on `UIViewController`. You already practically got it:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let tabBarVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainWindow") as? TabController {
    self.showViewController(tabBarVC, sender: self)
}
```

Also, note that you need to call `dismissViewController:completion:` inside `tabBarVC`.